# golang convert slice{0,1,2,3,4} to slice{1,2,3}?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I have dynamic slice of strings for example {"0s", "1s", "2s", "3s", "4s"}.
And I have dynamic slice of indexes for example {1, 2, 3}.
So i need only elements with index 1, 2 and 3 in slice.
Note both indexes slice and data slice are dynamic.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    indexes := []uint8{1, 2, 3}              //dynamic slice. maybe different elements and count
    data := []string{"0s", "1s", "2s", "3s", } //dynamic slice. maybe different elements and count

    // I need convert data to {"1s", "2s", "3s"} using indexes (dynamic) slice
    fmt.Println(data)
    fmt.Println(indexes)
}
```

here playground url https://play.golang.org/p/Vj0Vl5va4LP

Comment: Is `indexes` expected by continuous or could be jagged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note - your index slice is of type `[]uint8` - which is fine, but limits you to slices of max-length 256. This may be by design, but just something to be aware of.

Other solutions here use `append` - which is fine for small slices. But in general, when dealing with slices, if you know the final slice length, it is best to pre-allocate and write directly to indices and avoid `append` potentially performing multiple reallocations:

```
func correlate(vs []string, is []uint8) (s []string) {
    s = make([]string, len(is)) // pre-allocate results length - to avoid using append

    for j, i := range is {
        s[j] = vs[i]
    }
    return
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Et2VyoZzo59

Comment: Please be aware that this code panics if any element of `indexes` is greater than or equal to `len(vs)` i.e. in case of an invalid index value

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that the indices will be accurate at collection time & therefore would be redundant to recheck at rendering time.

Answer (score 8):

To create a new data slice with index values retrieved from index slice ,you have to iterate the index slice and pass the `value` of index slice as `index` of data slice.Below is the code with this logic

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    indexes := []uint8{1, 2, 3}
    data := []string{"0s", "1s", "2s", "3s"}
    var newData []string

    fmt.Println(data)
    fmt.Println(indexes)

    for _, v2 := range indexes {

        newData = append(newData, data[v2])
    }
    fmt.Println(newData)
}
```

Output :

```
[0s 1s 2s 3s]
[1 2 3]
[1s 2s 3s]
```

Comment: Please be aware that this code panics if any element of `indexes` is greater than or equal to `len(data)` i.e. in case of an invalid index value

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general solution that retrieves only the matched elements and discard if out of range.
https://play.golang.org/p/34vQnNh0jd4

```
func getElementsByIndexes(data []string, indexes []uint8) []string {
    res := make([]string, 0)
    l := len(data)
    
    for _, v := range indexes { 
        // discard if out of range
        if int(v) >= l {
            continue
        }
    
        res = append(res, data[int(v)])
    }

    return res
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i came to this pretty simple solution:

```
func filterByIndexes(sl []string, ind []int)[]string{
var filteredSlice []string
for index := range ind{
    // you may want to check for index out of range :)
    filteredSlice = append(filteredSlice, sl[index])
}
return filteredSlice
```

}

As commented, you may want to check for index out of range!